# Symfony 3 - Asset:install - Permission error

Tags: php, symfony

Doing the `php bin/console assets:install --symlink` command doesn't do anything.
To be clear : the `folder /bundle`s is created but it's empty.

With the verbose, I get this :

```
 Trying to install assets as absolute symbolic links.

13:54:13 DEBUG     [php] Warning: unlink(web/bundles/main): No such file or directory
[
  "exception" => Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\SilencedErrorContext {
    +count: 1,
    -severity: E_WARNING,
    trace: {
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:178: {
        :     },
        : } elseif (!@unlink($file) && file_exists($file)) {,
        :     $error = error_get_last();
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\AssetsInstallCommand.php:133: {
        : try {,
        :     $this->filesystem->remove($targetDir);,
        :
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:264: {
        : } else {,
        :     $statusCode = $this->execute($input, $output);,
        : }
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:887: {
        : if ($event->commandShouldRun()) {,
        :     $exitCode = $command->run($input, $output);,
        : } else {
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:223: {
        : $this->runningCommand = $command;,
        : $exitCode = $this->doRunCommand($command, $input, $output);,
        : $this->runningCommand = null;
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:81: {
        : ,
        :     return parent::doRun($input, $output);,
        : }
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:130: {
        :     $e = null;,
        :     $exitCode = $this->doRun($input, $output);,
        : } catch (\Exception $x) {
      },
      ***\Symfony\bin\console:28: {
        : $application = new Application($kernel);,
        : $application->run($input);,
        :
      }
    }
  }
]
[]
13:54:13 DEBUG     [php] Warning: unlink(web/bundles/coresphereconsole): No such file or directory
[
  "exception" => Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\SilencedErrorContext {
    +count: 1,
    -severity: E_WARNING,
    trace: {
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:178: {
        :     },
        : } elseif (!@unlink($file) && file_exists($file)) {,
        :     $error = error_get_last();
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\AssetsInstallCommand.php:133: {
        : try {,
        :     $this->filesystem->remove($targetDir);,
        :
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:264: {
        : } else {,
        :     $statusCode = $this->execute($input, $output);,
        : }
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:887: {
        : if ($event->commandShouldRun()) {,
        :     $exitCode = $command->run($input, $output);,
        : } else {
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:223: {
        : $this->runningCommand = $command;,
        : $exitCode = $this->doRunCommand($command, $input, $output);,
        : $this->runningCommand = null;
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:81: {
        : ,
        :     return parent::doRun($input, $output);,
        : }
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:130: {
        :     $e = null;,
        :     $exitCode = $this->doRun($input, $output);,
        : } catch (\Exception $x) {
      },
      ***\Symfony\bin\console:28: {
        : $application = new Application($kernel);,
        : $application->run($input);,
        :
      }
    }
  }
]
[]
13:54:13 DEBUG     [php] Warning: unlink(web/bundles\coresphereconsole): Permission denied
[
  "exception" => Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\SilencedErrorContext {
    +count: 1,
    -severity: E_WARNING,
    trace: {
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:167: {
        : // See https://bugs.php.net/52176,
        : if (!@(unlink($file) || '\\' !== DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR || rmdir($file)) && file_exists($file)) {,
        :     $error = error_get_last();
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\AssetsInstallCommand.php:161: {
        : if (!in_array($dir, $validAssetDirs)) {,
        :     $this->filesystem->remove($dir);,
        : }
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:264: {
        : } else {,
        :     $statusCode = $this->execute($input, $output);,
        : }
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:887: {
        : if ($event->commandShouldRun()) {,
        :     $exitCode = $command->run($input, $output);,
        : } else {
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:223: {
        : $this->runningCommand = $command;,
        : $exitCode = $this->doRunCommand($command, $input, $output);,
        : $this->runningCommand = null;
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:81: {
        : ,
        :     return parent::doRun($input, $output);,
        : }
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:130: {
        :     $e = null;,
        :     $exitCode = $this->doRun($input, $output);,
        : } catch (\Exception $x) {
      },
      ***\Symfony\bin\console:28: {
        : $application = new Application($kernel);,
        : $application->run($input);,
        :
      }
    }
  }
]
[]
13:54:13 DEBUG     [php] Warning: unlink(web/bundles\main): Permission denied
[
  "exception" => Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\SilencedErrorContext {
    +count: 1,
    -severity: E_WARNING,
    trace: {
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:167: {
        : // See https://bugs.php.net/52176,
        : if (!@(unlink($file) || '\\' !== DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR || rmdir($file)) && file_exists($file)) {,
        :     $error = error_get_last();
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\AssetsInstallCommand.php:161: {
        : if (!in_array($dir, $validAssetDirs)) {,
        :     $this->filesystem->remove($dir);,
        : }
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:264: {
        : } else {,
        :     $statusCode = $this->execute($input, $output);,
        : }
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:887: {
        : if ($event->commandShouldRun()) {,
        :     $exitCode = $command->run($input, $output);,
        : } else {
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:223: {
        : $this->runningCommand = $command;,
        : $exitCode = $this->doRunCommand($command, $input, $output);,
        : $this->runningCommand = null;
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:81: {
        : ,
        :     return parent::doRun($input, $output);,
        : }
      },
      ***\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:130: {
        :     $e = null;,
        :     $exitCode = $this->doRun($input, $output);,
        : } catch (\Exception $x) {
      },
      ***\Symfony\bin\console:28: {
        : $application = new Application($kernel);,
        : $application->run($input);,
        :
      }
    }
  }
]
[]
 ---- ---------------------------------- ------------------
       Bundle                             Method / Error
 ---- ---------------------------------- ------------------
  OK   MainBundle                         absolute symlink
       -> web/bundles/main
  OK   CoreSphereConsoleBundle            absolute symlink
       -> web/bundles/coresphereconsole
 ---- ---------------------------------- ------------------

 [OK] All assets were successfully installed.
```

I launched the console as administrator, cleaned the cache... 
It's really weird.

I'm using windows.

I think doing `php composer.phar update` broke something because it has updated symfony from `3.3.2` to `3.3.3` and installed `twig/extensions`.

It worked before that...

Thanks for the help !

Comment: if you do a composer update, it s normal that it change the symfony version ...

Comment: Yes it's not a problem for me, the problem is that since this update, i can't install my asset...
I don't know if it's related or not, just giving you everything I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUTO ANSWER : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23373

Seems to be a problem related to Symfony 3.3.3...